# Speaker & Piezo when beeping both cause CapacitiveSense to sense

Tags: piezo, buzzer, pcb-design, speaker

I am using this speaker:  CUI part number CSS-I4B20-SMT-TR as an alarm on a clock using atmega328 chip and Arduino IDE with the tone function. Works great.

I am also using Arduino CapacitiveSensor.h library.  Also works great.

**Problem:**  Want to touch the clock to put it in snooze when the alarm starts.  But when the speaker beeps, the speaker affects the Touch Sensor so it puts itself in snooze after one beep!

EMI is **not** the issue.  Tested with a second speaker beeping, running from a different Arduino.  Brought speaker close to the Touch Sense circuit and it DID NOT trigger. Can something be added/changed to prevent the beep pulses from affecting the rest of the circuit?

2. Change Speaker to Piezo Buzzer which does not have a coil.  I thought that was the answer until I read about the Piezo being a risk to the atmega328 from sending  voltage into the circuit and/or possibly drawing too much current.  I would think this could be solved using a resistor, transistor and diode.
   **This was tried. Piezo in circuit also was sensed when beeping.**

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, or Options I have not thought of. Thanks.

---

**Update:**  Changed to Murata piezo sounder with circuit shown below.  Still triggers Touch Sensor when beeping.

**Question**:  Is there a circuit change that could reduce the effect of the speaker on the rest of the circuit?

[image]

Comment: a connect a piezo directly (200 Ohm). did you try to replace the speaker with piezo in that circuit? and I why do you use an A pin for tone()?

Comment: Yes, did test a piezo in the circuit and it does work.  I then was concerned that the piezo could somehow damage the chip, but am not sure, not familiar with risks of using a piezo.  As far as using the Analog pin, I already used the PWM pins, and the tone function does work on the analog pin.  Are there advantages to using the tone function on a PWM pin?  If so, I can change things around to make a PWM pin available. thanks

Comment: See update above.  Piezo also causes EMI problem

Comment: Turns out it is NOT and EMI problem.  Speaker is affecting the circuit which the TouchSense circuit detects.  See updated problem statement.

Comment: are they still on pins next to each other?

Comment: One speaker is on a breadboard run by an Arduino. The speaker I am concerned with is on a PCB with the touch sense circuit run by an ATMEGA328PB chip.  I held the speaker on the breadboard while beeping right next to the PCB touch sense circuit and it did not sense the beeping speaker.

Comment: A reasonable amount of EMI happens to be on the cable and not through the air, so bringing the devices close to each other is not sufficient to test for EMI.

Comment: Yes true, and in the PCB traces.  I was surprised the Piezo speaker did not work. I hoped  eliminating the speaker coil would fix it. The CapacitiveSensor circuit is very sensitive. Is there any way to suppress the EMI from the speaker?

Comment: Well I solved it with software!  I have the CapacitiveSensor only active between beeps. Works great!